# Android Studio failed to sync Gradle

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Till yesterday everything was working properly in my application and I could program using `android studio` without any problems.But today when I ran the same application I encountered with this error:

```
> Failed to sync  project<br/> Error:Unknown host services.gradle.org.<br/> Learn
> about configuring HTTP proxies in Gradle
```

I've tried some solutions but didn't work .really don't know what happened.

Here is my system software specification:
Android studio version : 1.0.1
JDK version :1.8

Comment: Can you open "services.gradle.org" using browser?

Comment: Can you show us the gradle?

Comment: yes . and i could programming in AS without internet connection , too .

Comment: I restarted my system and faced with new errors !

Comment: Did you got an option to upgrade your Gradle?If yes please upgrade it and then run the app. @HAMED

Answer (score 0):

Settings > HTTP Proxy > Auto-detect proxy settings

and try to check your Internet connection

Answer (score 0):

Try  To Invalidate Cache And Restart Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to File -> Invalidate caches / Restart
2. Shutdown Android Studio
3. Rename/remove .gradle folder in the user home directory
4. Restart Android Studio (It will download gradle metadata and data)
5. Gradle build succeed
6. Rebuild project. Done.

Answer (score 0):

Add this proxy information to your `gradle.properties` file:

```
systemProp.https.proxyPort=9595
systemProp.http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.https.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.http.proxyPort=9595
```

and set above proxy port (ex. 9595) in your vpn like psiphone.
Then sync project.